# How to generate private/public key pair for client-side REST authentication?

Tags: java, rest, authentication, cookies, restlet

I'm using `Restlet` framework to provide some RESTful resource URIs. I need authentication for every action, but I don't want to maintain server-side states. `Restlet` supports using Client-Side cookies for authentication, and I've personally verified this by deploying a cookie with a static string in it, and then trying to find that cookie during another request, and verifying authentication by matching the string inside the cookie.

But instead of just writing any string, I now want to write something which can be used for actual authentication.

So how do I generate a private public key pair in Java, such that the private key is kept in code and is always the same (even after stopping/starting the Web Application), and different public keys are generating using the private key, which I can then put into the cookies ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a big fan of using Cookies for RESTful applications.  In theory RESTful applications should be stateless, meaning that from request to request the client should always tell the server what needs to occur without reliance on a previous request.

That being said, I would perform authentication every request that the client makes.

You can do several different types of authentication per request:

- [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) - I would recommend doing this over https so that the password is never seen in plain text.
- [Mutual Authentication via Certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication) - This would require the client to provide a certificate to the server identifying who the client is.  This is a great way of doing authentication, quite secure, but it is difficult to deal with when things go wrong or if someone wasn't paying attention while setting things up.  Great detail is required to get everything right and it is easy to mess up.  Finally, certificates eventually expire and people have to remember to renew them, major pain.
- [OAuth Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) - OAuth is an interesting alternative to both Basic and Mutual authentications.  It is based on tokens.  Easier to maintain then certificates in the long run.

Try not to be too concerned about the authentication overhead per request.  It should be quite small compared to the rest of the request (hopefully).